# Move li from one ul to another ul in top

Tags: jquery

I have this code, where i move a `<li>` element to one `<ul>` to another. But my `<li>` will be placed in the bottom. how can i do, so it will be placed at the top?

```
$(cbox).parents('li').appendTo('#taskopen');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use [prependTo()](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

```
$(cbox).parents('li').prependTo('#taskopen');
```